# YouTube Data API serves video MetaData in apk, but gives empty data in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, metadata, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, api-key

I have an Android miniApp that works fine as an apk, but gets empty data when running in the Android Studio emulator. The program uses as a parameter the videoID (the code to uniquely identify a youtube video) to ask the YouTube Data API for the metadata of that given video.

I suppose that the code must be exactly the same to make it work as an apk and also in the emulator, right? So the difference should be in the type of credentials necessary to overcome the puzzle of youtube data api permissions. Frankly, I am just guessing here because I do not know EXACTLY which permissions to get. I already tried with these two debugging keys:

**API keys**

*Name Creation date Restrictions Key*
Permisos API key Nov 18, 2017 None AIzaSyB7nf6ibfy8X2QuhhlrF3bRyl3RFFZ2IYI

**OAuth 2.0 client IDs**

*Name Creation date Type Client ID*
Permisos Android client Nov 18, 2017 Android 68030531187-8rod8vs8edb8ic8aim72m7jlg71brmsh.apps.googleusercontent.com

Notice that the query to the YouTube Data API server is entirely a READ Only operation in my code (I am not writing or uploading anything there), so I would only need simpler permissions, right?

So, what else am I missing here? Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Logically, I include the source code:

```
package com.dtek.youtube;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.ExponentialBackOff;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Caption;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CaptionListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.CaptionSnippet;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
private Button mCallApiButton, mDownloadCaption;
ProgressDialog mProgress;
private LinearLayout llMetaData, llMain;
private TextView tvMetaTitle, tvMetaDescription, tvMetaDuration, tvCaption;
private ImageView ivMetaThumb;
private EditText etVideoId;
private String videoId = "";
static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1000;
static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 1001;
static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1002;
static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS = 1003;

private static final String BUTTON_TEXT = "Call YouTube Data API";
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
private static final String[] SCOPES = {YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY};

/**
 * Create the main activity.
 * @param savedInstanceState previously saved instance data.
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etVideoId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_video_id);
    llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_ll);
    llMetaData = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.metadata_ll);
    tvMetaTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvMetaDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    tvMetaDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duration);
    tvCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption);
    ivMetaThumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    mCallApiButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    mDownloadCaption = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download_caption);
    mCallApiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallApiButton.setEnabled(false);
            getResultsFromApi();
            mCallApiButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgress.setMessage("Calling YouTube Data API ...");

    // Initialize credentials and service object.
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
}



/**
 * Attempt to call the API, after verifying that all the preconditions are
 * satisfied. The preconditions are: Google Play Services installed, an
 * account was selected and the device currently has online access. If any
 * of the preconditions are not satisfied, the app will prompt the user as
 * appropriate.
 */
private void getResultsFromApi() {
    if (! isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        acquireGooglePlayServices();
    } else if (mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
        chooseAccount();
    } else if (! isDeviceOnline()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No network connection available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        videoId = etVideoId.getEditableText().toString();

        new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
    }
}

/**
 * Attempts to set the account used with the API credentials. If an account
 * name was previously saved it will use that one; otherwise an account
 * picker dialog will be shown to the user. Note that the setting the
 * account to use with the credentials object requires the app to have the
 * GET_ACCOUNTS permission, which is requested here if it is not already
 * present. The AfterPermissionGranted annotation indicates that this
 * function will be rerun automatically whenever the GET_ACCOUNTS permission
 * is granted.
 */
@AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
private void chooseAccount() {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
            this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
        String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        if (accountName != null) {
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
            getResultsFromApi();
        } else {
            // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
            startActivityForResult(
                    mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                    REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }
    } else {
        // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                this,
                "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when an activity launched here (specifically, AccountPicker
 * and authorization) exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 * @param requestCode code indicating which activity result is incoming.
 * @param resultCode code indicating the result of the incoming
 *     activity result.
 * @param data Intent (containing result data) returned by incoming
 *     activity result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "This app requires Google Play Services. Please install " +
                                "Google Play Services on your device and relaunch this app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.apply();
                    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    getResultsFromApi();
                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getResultsFromApi();
            }
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Respond to requests for permissions at runtime for API 23 and above.
 * @param requestCode The request code passed in
 *     requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, String, int, String[])
 * @param permissions The requested permissions. Never null.
 * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
 *     which is either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

/**
 * Callback for when a permission is granted using the EasyPermissions
 * library.
 * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
 *         permission
 * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
 */
@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Do nothing.
}

/**
 * Callback for when a permission is denied using the EasyPermissions
 * library.
 * @param requestCode The request code associated with the requested
 *         permission
 * @param list The requested permission list. Never null.
 */
@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Do nothing.
}

/**
 * Checks whether the device currently has a network connection.
 * @return true if the device has a network connection, false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isDeviceOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

/**
 * Check that Google Play services APK is installed and up to date.
 * @return true if Google Play Services is available and up to
 *     date on this device; false otherwise.
 */
private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    return connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * Attempt to resolve a missing, out-of-date, invalid or disabled Google
 * Play Services installation via a user dialog, if possible.
 */
private void acquireGooglePlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int connectionStatusCode =
            apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(connectionStatusCode)) {
        showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(connectionStatusCode);
    }
}


/**
 * Display an error dialog showing that Google Play Services is missing
 * or out of date.
 * @param connectionStatusCode code describing the presence (or lack of)
 *     Google Play Services on this device.
 */
void showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
        final int connectionStatusCode) {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    Dialog dialog = apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
            MainActivity.this,
            connectionStatusCode,
            REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}

/**
 * An asynchronous task that handles the YouTube Data API call.
 * Placing the API calls in their own task ensures the UI stays responsive.
 */
private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, VideoListResponse> {
    private com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("YouTube Data API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call YouTube Data API.
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected VideoListResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch information about the "GoogleDevelopers" YouTube channel.
     * @return List of Strings containing information about the channel.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private VideoListResponse getDataFromApi() {
        VideoListResponse response = null;
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
            if(videoId == null || videoId.length() == 0)
                parameters.put("id", "Ks-_Mh1QhMc");
            else
                parameters.put("id", videoId);
            YouTube.Videos.List videosListByIdRequest = mService.videos().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
            if (parameters.containsKey("id") && parameters.get("id") != "") {
                videosListByIdRequest.setId(parameters.get("id").toString());
            }

            response = videosListByIdRequest.execute();
        }catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode()
                    + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        llMetaData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(VideoListResponse output) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (output == null || output.getItems().size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No results returned.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
            setMetaDataView(output);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (mLastError != null) {
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
            } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The following error occurred:\n"
                        + mLastError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private class MakeCaptionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Caption>> {

    private com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube mService = null;
    private Exception mLastError = null;

    MakeCaptionTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        mService = new com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("YouTube Data API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Background task to call YouTube Data API.
     * @param params no parameters needed for this task.
     */
    @Override
    protected List<Caption> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return getDataFromApi();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetch information about the "GoogleDevelopers" YouTube channel.
     * @return List of Strings containing information about the channel.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private List<Caption> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet");
        parameters.put("videoId", "M7FIvfx5J10");
        parameters.put("onBehalfOfContentOwner", "");

        YouTube.Captions.List captionsListRequest = mService.captions().list(parameters.get("part").toString(), parameters.get("videoId").toString());
        if (parameters.containsKey("onBehalfOfContentOwner") && parameters.get("onBehalfOfContentOwner") != "") {
            captionsListRequest.setOnBehalfOfContentOwner(parameters.get("onBehalfOfContentOwner").toString());
        }

        CaptionListResponse captionListResponse = captionsListRequest.execute();
        List<Caption> captions = captionListResponse.getItems();
        // Print information from the API response.
        System.out.println("\n================== Returned Caption Tracks ==================\n");
        CaptionSnippet snippet;
        for (Caption caption : captions) {
            snippet = caption.getSnippet();
            System.out.println("  - ID: " + caption.getId());
            System.out.println("  - Name: " + snippet.getName());
            System.out.println("  - Language: " + snippet.getLanguage());
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        }

        return captions;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Caption> output) {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No results returned.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
            try {
                setCaptionView(output);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgress.hide();
        if (mLastError != null) {
            if (mLastError instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) {
                showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                        ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException) mLastError)
                                .getConnectionStatusCode());
            } else if (mLastError instanceof UserRecoverableAuthIOException) {
                startActivityForResult(
                        ((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The following error occurred:\n"
                        + mLastError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Downloads a caption track for a YouTube video. (captions.download)
 *
 * @param captionId The id parameter specifies the caption ID for the resource
 * that is being downloaded. In a caption resource, the id property specifies the
 * caption track's ID.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void downloadCaption(String captionId) throws IOException {
    // Create an API request to the YouTube Data API's captions.download
    // method to download an existing caption track.
    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    YouTube youtube = new com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
            .setApplicationName("YouTube Data API Android Quickstart")
            .build();
    YouTube.Captions.Download captionDownload = youtube.captions().download(captionId).setTfmt("srt");

    // Set the download type and add an event listener.
    MediaHttpDownloader downloader = captionDownload.getMediaHttpDownloader();

    // Indicate whether direct media download is enabled. A value of
    // "True" indicates that direct media download is enabled and that
    // the entire media content will be downloaded in a single request.
    // A value of "False," which is the default, indicates that the
    // request will use the resumable media download protocol, which
    // supports the ability to resume a download operation after a
    // network interruption or other transmission failure, saving
    // time and bandwidth in the event of network failures.
    downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(false);

    // Set the download state for the caption track file.
    MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener downloadProgressListener = new MediaHttpDownloaderProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) throws IOException {
            switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
                case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                    System.out.println("Download in progress");
                    System.out.println("Download percentage: " + downloader.getProgress());
                    break;
                // This value is set after the entire media file has
                //  been successfully downloaded.
                case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                    System.out.println("Download Completed!");
                    break;
                // This value indicates that the download process has
                //  not started yet.
                case NOT_STARTED:
                    System.out.println("Download Not Started!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    downloader.setProgressListener(downloadProgressListener);

    OutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream("captionFile.srt");
    // Download the caption track.
    captionDownload.executeAndDownloadTo(outputFile);
}

private void setMetaDataView(VideoListResponse videoListResponse){
    llMetaData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvMetaTitle.setText("Title \n" + videoListResponse.getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getTitle());
    tvMetaDescription.setText("Description \n" + videoListResponse.getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getDescription());
    tvMetaDuration.setText("Duration \n" + videoListResponse.getItems().get(0).getContentDetails().getDuration());
    Picasso.with(this).load(videoListResponse.getItems().get(0).getSnippet().getThumbnails().getStandard().getUrl()).into(ivMetaThumb);
    if(videoListResponse.getItems().get(0).getContentDetails().getCaption().equals("true")){
//            GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
//                    getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList("YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner"))
//                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
//            new MakeCaptionTask(credential).execute();
        tvCaption.setText("Caption is present");
    }
}

private void setCaptionView(List<Caption> captions) throws IOException {
    tvCaption.setText(captions.get(0).getSnippet().getName());
    downloadCaption(captions.get(0).getId());
}

}
```

Permissions in the Manifest file: INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, GET_ACCOUNTS.

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dtek.youtube"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev186-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution? for me it says `the following error occurred null`

Comment: I could not find a solution. I wanted to include the YouTubePlayer and YouTubeData objects in my Android App, but they revealed themselves as quite unsuitable for the final requirements of my App, so I ended up weeding out these codings from my program.

Comment: Google does not produce a COMPLETE and good step-by-step guide which actually RUNS and WORKS. Their engineers have a very faulty idea of how an educational material should be made.

Comment: To add more anger to the situation, I payed an Indian developer 200 bucks to code me a miniApp where the YouTubeData API was queried about metadata info from a YouTube video. He managed to make it work, but never explained how he did with the permissions riddle. He wanted more money to "start" explaining so! If you want, I can send you the source code of this Android miniApp. Cheers.

Comment: thanks for feedback yeah would be great look at this app if it really works then mb I could find out something. please send to willalwaysdie@gmail.com